# How to run a JQuery function on page load MVC asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a JQuery function `FetchFunctions()` that I need to run when the page is loaded.  I am not sure how to do this within MVC using a template.  I don't have a  section on this page.  Adding it to the _layout page doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside of your page just add a script tag

somepage.cshtml

```
<script>
 window.onload = function(){
  //script goes here
 };
 //or if you prefer jQuery
 $(function(){
  //script goes here
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just include the following in your HTML:

```
<script>
    $(function () { FetchFunctions() });
</script>
```